# How to use WM_COPY to get selected text in the focused window in c++

Tags: c++

I want to use WM_COPY in c++ using windows32 api to get the selcted text whenever a hotkey is pressed int the focused window.
Hotkey: say, alt+1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: WM_COPY is a *request* to have an Edit control put its text onto the Windows clipboard. There is no guarantee that the request is honored. And it doesn't get you the text anyway, you would have to pull the text from the clipboard afterwards. To get the text directly, you should use EM_GETSEL/EM_EXSETSEL and WM_GETTEXT instead.